# Intersection between two collection

Tags: performance, collections, intersection

I was asked this interview question. Best and efficient way to get the intersection between two collections, one very big and the other small. Java Collection basically

Answer (score 0):

With no other information what you can do is to save time when performing the `n x m` comparisons as follows:

1. Let `big` and `small` be the collections of size `n` and `m`.
2. Let `intersection` be the intersecting collection (empty for now).
3. Let `hashes` be the collection of hashes of all elements in `small`.
4. For each `object` in `big` let `h` be its hash integer.
5. For each `hash` value in the `hashes` collection, if`hash = h`, then compare `object` with the element of `small` whose hash is `hash`. If they are equal, add `object` to `intersection`.

So, the idea is to compare hashes instead of objects and only compare objects if their hashes coincide.

Note that the additional collection for the hashes of `small` is acceptable because of the size of this supposedly small collection. Notice also that the algorithm computes `n + m` hash values and comparatively few object comparisons.

Here is the code in Smalltalk

```
set := small asSet.
^big select: [:o | set includes: o]
```

The Smalltalk code is very compact because the message `includes:` sent to `set` works as described in step 5 above. It first compares hashes and then objects if needed. The `select:` is also a very compact way to express the selection in step 5.

**UPDATE**

If we enumerate all the comparisons between the elements of both collections we would have to consider `n x m` pairs of objects, which would account for a complexity of order `O(nm)` (big-O notation). On the other hand, if we put the small collection into a hashed one (as I did in the Smalltalk example) the inner testing that happens every time we have to check if `small` includes an object of `big` will have a complexity of `O(1)`. And given that hashing the `small` collection is `O(m)`, the total complexity of this method would be `O(n + m)`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the two collections `large` and `small`, respectively.

The Java `Collection` is an `Abstract` class - you cannot actually use it directly - you have to use one of `Collection`'s concrete sub-classes. For this problem, you can use `Set`s.  A `Set` has only unique elements, and it has a method `contains(Object o)`.  And it's subclass, `SortedSet`, is created in ascending order, by default.

So copy `small` into a `Set`. It's now got no duplicate values.  Copy `large` into a second `Set`, and this way we can use its `contains()` method. Create a third Set called `intersection`, to hold the intersection results.

`for-each` element in `small` check if `large.contains(element_from_small)` Every time you find a match, `intersection.add(element_from_small)`

At the end of the run through `small`, you'll have the intersection of all objects in both original collections, with no duplicates.  If you want it ordered, copy it into a `SortedSet` and it'll then be in ascending order.